# Javascript for loop in map

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, jvectormap

If you're reading, I have been trying to understand / work out how to do this for days.

I'm using jvectormap and have done everything such as return my users latitude and longitude in an array.

I even have a javascript function that prints the array of each clients latitude and longitude so I know it works.

I just need to somehow include my javascript foreach loop in to my map function.

The following code works but only by manually entering the markers :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/get_dash_map.php",
    context: document.body,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {get_data_:true},
    success: function(value_) {
        const data_ = JSON.parse(value_);
        const $parent = $('#all-the-coordinates');

        for(const row of data_){
            //const $element = $('<span></span>');
            //$element.text(`${row['client_latitude']}, ${row['client_longitude']}, `);
            //$parent.append($element);
        }

        $('#map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            zoomOnScroll: false,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            markerStyle: { initial: { fill: '#F8E23B', stroke: '#383f47' } },
            markers: [
                {latLng: ['51.5605', '0.4524'], name: 'BenzaHdd'},
            ]
        })
}})
</script>
```

As you can see, the markers are being set manually by me.

I need the markers in there to loop for each users latitude and longitude I get.

I tried revamping the code above to work but I failed. My try looked like this :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/get_dash_map.php",
    context: document.body,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {get_data_:true},
    success: function(value_) {
        const data_ = JSON.parse(value_);
        const $parent = $('#all-the-coordinates');

        $('#map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            zoomOnScroll: false,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            markerStyle: { initial: { fill: '#F8E23B', stroke: '#383f47' } },

            for(const row of data_) {
            //const $element = $('<span></span>');
            //$element.text(`${row['client_latitude']}, ${row['client_longitude']}, `);
            //$parent.append($element);
            markers: [ { latLng: [`${row['client_latitude']}, ${row['client_longitude']}`], name: 'Benza' } ],

            },
        })
}})
</script>
```

***get_dash_map.php*** :

```
    $user_grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users");


    while ($users_ = mysqli_fetch_array($user_grab)) {
        $client_ip = $users_['ip'];

        //This is for getting each users location on our map
        $ip               = $client_ip;
        $geocode          = 
        file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}");
        $output           = json_decode($geocode);
        $client_latitude  = $output->latitude;
        $client_longitude = $output->longitude;

        $response_[] = [$client_latitude, $client_longitude];            
    }

    echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($response_), ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

***NEW CODE***

```
<script>
function fetchMap() {
$.ajax({
url: "includes/get_dash_map.php",
context: document.body,
type: 'POST',
data: {get_data:true},
success: function(value) {

    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'world_mill_en',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        zoomOnScroll: false,
        hoverOpacity: 0.7,
        markerStyle: { initial: { fill: '#F8E23B', stroke: '#383f47' } },
        markers: () => value.map(row =>{ return {latLng: [`${row['0']},${row['1']}`], name: `${row['0']}`}})
        //markers: [
        //    {latLng: ['51.5605', '0.4524'], name: 'BenzaHdd'},
        //]
    })
   },
});
}
$(document).ready(function() { fetchMap(); });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the JSON you get back from your call to `includes/get_dash_map.php` - `console.log(data_ )` should do that

Comment: @Jamiec When I use my modified code, I don't get anything. It doesn't show the map. It doesn't even show a request from the get_dash_map.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. Directly after the line `const data_ = JSON.parse(value_);` if you put `console.log(data_)` do you see anything in the console?

Comment: @Jamiec oh okay. No I don't see anything.

Comment: Then your problem is not with your map, its with your ajax request! Until you get something back, nothing you do will show anything on your map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add markers this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/get_dash_map.php",
    context: document.body,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {get_data_:true},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data_) {
        const $parent = $('#all-the-coordinates');

        $('#map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            zoomOnScroll: false,
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            markerStyle: { initial: { fill: '#F8E23B', stroke: '#383f47' } },
            markers: data_.map(function(row){
                 return {latLng: [row[0], row[1]], name: 'Ben'}
            })
        })
     }
 });
```

But I'd rather prepared the correct json on the server-side.

Comment: I'm using this : https://pastebin.com/P5VFiuLM but it doesn't show the map still.

Comment: I just realised when I went to my get_dash_map page, it echoed client_latitude[values here] and longitude[values here] which would corrupt the map becuase it only wants to read values, not strings. Now I have done that, it's got a final [ ]. I just removed these square brackets and now I see this [Image here](https://gyazo.com/6d8e55420ba5b8e95bec8dbaa26b4957) Any ideas why my map is still not showing up ? [I'm using this](https://pastebin.com/hBujBJ0m)

Comment: @Ben, please add the response of `includes/get_dash_map.php` to your question. Looks like we're parsing it incorrectly. From your question I can guess I must be something like this: `[{client_latitude: 23.456, client_longitude:-76.456, name:'Ben'}, {client_latitude: 25.456, client_longitude:-80.456, name:'Jack'}, {client_latitude: 26.456, client_longitude:-99.456, name:'Charlie'}, ...]`

Comment: No. When I get print the client_latitude and client_longitude, it shows them all

Comment: this still isn't showing my map. Is it correct that my values should be returning [Like this](https://gyazo.com/4d578a648c56242d982da7bc807c6976)

Comment: No, it's not correct, it sould be an array of arrays, or array of objects.

Comment: Exactly like this.

Comment: Yes, my map still does not load. Not sure if this is any help [Image here](https://gyazo.com/dea654c56a0229bf2a6b7d39053b070c). + It's not getting the get_dash_map.php in my console log on chrome

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `{` at line 307 in your `members.php`.

Comment: It's not in the `members.php` itself, but in the page it returns to the browser.

Comment: Look here https://pastebin.com/qnwHgmh8 (It wouldnt let me show you the code properly on here because of the character I used.

Comment: I've fixed that. My map is now showing but no markers are showing.

Comment: @Ben, I've updated my answer again. Looks like I've missed the brackets to be removed: `markers: data_.map(function(row){return {latLng: [row[0], row[1]], name: 'Ben'},})`

Comment: for some reason, your code does not display the map. The code that displays the map is : https://pastebin.com/KXeATwY1 but no markers show.

Comment: @Ben, Looks like I need to sleep... I've missed the comma at the very end of the expression: `markers: data_.map(function(row){return {latLng: [row[0], row[1]], name: 'Ben'},})`. Please remove it. I've also updated the answer again.

Comment: ! Thank you so much! Now it all works perfectly. +1 <3

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use a function that returns an array :

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
     markers: () => {
         let markers_array = [];
         for(let row of data_) {
              markers_array.push( {latLng... } )  // Make your loop here
          }
          return markers_array;
     }
})
```

Alternatively, using `data_.map()` :

```
$('#map').vectorMap({
     markers: () => data_.map( row => {
          return { row.latLng... } // Make your loop here
     })
})
```

I have used ES6 because you used the `const` keyword. For that matter, it should not be `const` but `let`, as it's in a loop, so it's variable.

Comment: I haven't what?

Comment: I just tried your version - https://pastebin.com/mVYVjgiE but the map is still not showing up.

Comment: I just realised when I went to my get_dash_map page, it echoed client_latitude[values here] and longitude[values here] which would corrupt the map becuase it only wants to read values, not strings. Now I have done that, it's got a final [ ] around the values. How could I remove these ? [Image Proof Here](https://gyazo.com/140022765325a332a1a47612b73d6311)

Comment: uh, I don't know, it's hard to answer blindly without seeing your code. Besides, that's another problem, so that should be asked as a new question.